# MSW (Mock Service Worker) + Vite: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, vite, msw

I'm installing the service following the steps at the official docs: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/install

This piece of code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const { worker } = require('../tests/mocks/browser');
  worker.start();
}

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I've setup the project using Vite.
What's the correct approach to solving this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vite does not use require, try to use import instead:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const { worker } = await import('../tests/mocks/browser');
  worker.start();
}
```

Source (albeit another issue, but works here as well): https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3409#issuecomment-841049875

Comment: Works fine to me. await and import instead of require.

Comment: Thanks for answering this one! We will update the docs in MSW to feature `import` by default in the nearest future.